# Wrong Value returned for If Condition PLSQL

Tags: if-statement, plsql, cursor, compare

In the following PLSQL function where I want to return the "Customer" value if no "Notify Party" exists.

The result always returns the Value for the condition "CUSTOMER even thou there exists a "Notify Party". Why is that?
I have used this same function but with `involved_party_qual_gid in ('CONSIGNEE', 'CUSTOMER')`
and it worked fine producing the required results.

```
function getNotifyPartyOrCustomer(orderID varchar2) return varchar2

is
NameResult varchar2(100);

CURSOR c_involved_party is
  select involved_party_contact_gid, involved_party_qual_gid
    from order_release_inv_party
   where involved_party_qual_gid in ('NOTIFY PARTY', 'CUSTOMER')
     and order_release_gid = orderID;
begin

for i in c_involved_party loop

  if i.involved_party_qual_gid = 'NOTIFY PARTY' then
    NameResult := i.involved_party_contact_gid;
    return(NameResult);

  elsif i.involved_party_qual_gid = 'CUSTOMER' then
    NameResult := i.involved_party_contact_gid;
    return(NameResult);
  end if;
 end loop;

end;
```

I have written alternative two functions that produce the same results:

1- Function 1

```
function getNotifyPartyOrCustomer(orderID varchar2) return varchar2

 is
  NameResult varchar2(100);

 begin

   select coalesce((select involved_party_contact_gid
                  from order_release_inv_party
                 where involved_party_qual_gid = 'NOTIFY PARTY'
                   and order_release_gid = orderID),

                (select involved_party_contact_gid
                   from order_release_inv_party
                  where involved_party_qual_gid = 'CUSTOMER'
                    and order_release_gid = orderID), 

                'NO DATA'

                ) AS NAME
   INTO NameResult

   from DUAL;

  return NameResult;
end;
```

2- Function 2

```
function getNotifyPartyOrCustomer(orderID varchar2) return varchar2

 is
   NameResult varchar2(100);


 begin

    select involved_party_contact_gid
    INTO NameResult
    from order_release_inv_party
   where involved_party_qual_gid in ('NOTIFY PARTY')
     and order_release_gid = orderID;

   return(NameResult);

     exception WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN

      select involved_party_contact_gid
        into NameResult
        from order_release_inv_party
       where involved_party_qual_gid in ('CUSTOMER')
         and order_release_gid = orderID;   



 return(NameResult);
end;
```

But I'm not happy with those two functions, since first,, performance wise, I don't see the point of having to retrieve from the same table twice when I can simply get the results in one retrieval and do my logic on it, and second because I need the if conditions for other logic.

I just need to know why it does not work.

Appreciate ALL the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of your first function will depend on the order that the query returns the rows in. Since you're not providing an `order by` clause, the database can return the rows in any order. If you want to prioritize "NOTIFY PARTY" over "CUSTOMER", you can add the following to the query:

`order by involved_party_qual_gid desc`

Your other function that is working acceptably is probably doing so coincidentally. It could change if something causes the database to return the rows in a different order (such as restoring from backup, reorganizing an index, or even just enough data in the table to change the plan).

---

**Follow-up**

Typically, when you're dealing with SQL, if you're iterating over a result set, then you're taking a poor approach. Database engines are really good at dealing with set-based problems, so it's typically best to let the engine deal with as much of the work as you can.

In this case, it looks like you don't really care about the results of each row: really you just want the first row that contains "NOTIFY PARTY" and, if no such record exists, you want the first row that contains "CUSTOMER". Let's say your result set returns 500 rows. Why would you want to iterate over all 500, when you only care about the value of 1 row? If I were writing this function, I'd lose the iteration altogether:

```
function getNotifyPartyOrCustomer(orderID varchar2) return varchar2 is
NameResult varchar2(100);

CURSOR c_involved_party is
  select involved_party_contact_gid
    from order_release_inv_party
   where involved_party_qual_gid in ('NOTIFY PARTY', 'CUSTOMER')
     and order_release_gid = orderID
   order by involved_party_qual_gid desc;

v_contact_gid order_release_inv_party.involved_party_contact_gid%type;
begin

open c_involved_party;
fetch c_involved_party into v_contact_gid;
close c_involved_party;

return v_contact_gid;

end getNotifyPartyOrCustomer;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Allan, a simple answer and I just couldn't see it.
Also if you don't mind, is there another better way to do the function? Or is this good enough.
Thanks alot I appreciate it.

Comment: Also, I'm trying to think of a way of having to iterate over the list without having to depend on the order which the query returns the rows.
i.e. looping over entire list before applying the if condition,
any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks again for the followup Allan, sincerely appreciate it. :)
Exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works - sorry in case there is any syntax or compilation issue, but you get the idea -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getnotifypartyorcustomer (orderid VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   nameresult   VARCHAR2 (100);

   CURSOR c_involved_party
   IS
      SELECT CASE
                WHEN involved_party_contact_gid =
                                         'CUSTOMER'
                   THEN involved_party_qual_gid
                ELSE NULL
             END involved_party_qual_gid_a,
             CASE
                WHEN involved_party_contact_gid =
                                     'NOTIFY PARTY'
                   THEN involved_party_qual_gid
                ELSE NULL
             END involved_party_qual_gid_b
        FROM order_release_inv_party
       WHERE involved_party_qual_gid IN ('NOTIFY PARTY', 'CUSTOMER')
         AND order_release_gid = orderid;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN c_involved_party
   LOOP
      nameresult :=
         NVL (NVL (i.involved_party_qual_gid_a, i.involved_party_qual_gid_b),
              'NONE'
             );
   END LOOP;

   RETURN (nameresult);
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS 
    RETURN nameresult;
    -- or RAISE if You Want
END;
```

or

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getnotifypartyorcustomer (orderid VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   nameresult   VARCHAR2 (100);
BEGIN
SELECT NVL (NVL (involved_party_qual_gid_a, involved_party_qual_gid_b),'NONE')
  INTO nameresult
  FROM (SELECT CASE
                  WHEN involved_party_contact_gid =
                                         'CUSTOMER'
                     THEN involved_party_qual_gid
                  ELSE NULL
               END involved_party_qual_gid_a,
               CASE
                  WHEN involved_party_contact_gid =
                                     'NOTIFY PARTY'
                     THEN involved_party_qual_gid
                  ELSE NULL
               END involved_party_qual_gid_b
          FROM order_release_inv_party
         WHERE involved_party_qual_gid IN ('NOTIFY PARTY', 'CUSTOMER')
           AND order_release_gid = orderid)
       );

   RETURN (nameresult);
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS 
    RETURN NULL ;
    -- RETURN 'NONE' ;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, appreciate it.....
It's also another way to do it and it opened my mind to ways of doing it...Thanks again